Use a Named Column for Reference instead of Cell Offset
I have a list of email addresses in a column.  Using the Name Manager, I've named the entire column, $Q:$Q as "Email".
I have a macro that strings the emails together if their row is marked with an 'a';
For Each Cell In RangeToConsider
    If Cell.Value = "a" Or Cell.Value = "A" Then
        strAddresses = strAddresses & "; " & Cell.Offset(0, 6).Value
    End If
Next

How do I used the Named Column instead of the Cell.Offset(0, 6).Value?
I've tried;
Cell.Offset(0, Range("Email").Column.Value

which doesn't return an error but also doesn't return any values.

Cell.Offset(0, 6).Value ---> Cells(cell.Row, Range("Email").Column).Value

Thank you!  Where do I go to study to know how to do that?  I've been searching all over and nothing lead me to that logic.

I'm not sure of an official source. You could theoretically use Offset, but it's clunky here.

@Neuner "CompanyName need another "

regarding where to 'study' this?  it's related to named ranges and utilization of named ranged.  you would have to extrapolate that the named range is a range and has properties which can be accessed, e.g., .column.

@BigBen Cells(cell.Row, Range("Email").Column).Value --> Range("Email").Cells(cell.Row).Value

@rotabor that does work. My comment was influenced by OP's previous question, where the named range did not appear to be an entire column. Obviously your solution will fail if the named range spans multiple columns (not the case here, but in a way another hidden requirement).

@BigBen Sure, each solution for each problem.

Named Entire Column Instead of Offset
Dim rangeToConsider As Range ' just to compile (previously referenced)
Dim strAddresses As String ' just to compile (previously declared)

Dim rangeEmail As Range:
Set rangeEmail = rangeToConsider.Worksheet.Range("Email")

Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In rangeToConsider.Cells ' assuming it's a single-column range
    ' This comparison is case-insensitive i.e. 'A = a'.
    If StrComp(CStr(cell.Value), "A", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then ' is equal
        strAddresses = strAddresses & "; " & rangeEmail(cell.Row).Value
    End If
Next cell

Dim rangeToConsider As Range ' just to compile (previously referenced)
Dim strAddresses As String ' just to compile (previously declared)

Dim EmailColumn As Long:
EmailColumn = rangeToConsider.Worksheet.Range("Email").Column

Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In rangeToConsider.Cells ' assuming it's a single-column range
    ' This comparison is case-insensitive i.e. 'A = a'.
    If StrComp(CStr(cell.Value), "A", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then ' is equal
        strAddresses = strAddresses & "; " _
            & cell.EntireRow.Columns(EmailColumn).Value
    End If
Next cell


rangeToConsider.Worksheet.Range("Email") evidently links ranges to the single worksheet, which is not obligatory, same as cell.EntireRow.Columns(EmailColumn).

Your solution is here:
To directly reference and use the named range
Function GetDistributionList(RangeToConsider As Range) As String
  Dim cell As Range, strAddresses As String
  For Each cell In RangeToConsider
      If LCase(cell.Value) = "a" Then
          strAddresses = strAddresses & "; " & Range("Email").Cells(cell.Row)
      End If
  Next
  GetDistributionList = Mid(strAddresses, 3)
End Sub

You can address the named column and select the cell within by the row number.
Alternatively, you can use the next calculation directly on the worksheet (RangeToConsider is column's name like Email):
A1 = TEXTJOIN("; ",TRUE,IF(LOWER(RangeToConsider)="a",Email,""))

